# A specified Include path is not valid. Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, lazy-loading

I am getting the following error when trying to run a query in EF.
A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'InvestmentClub' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'ClubMembers'.

**Query**

```
return _context.InvestmentClubs.Where(x => x.InvestmentClubId == clubId)
                       .Include(x => x.Policies).Include(x => x.ClubMembers).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Investmentclub class**

```
public class InvestmentClub
{
    public int InvestmentClubId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public InvestmentClubType ClubType { get; set; }

    //Navigation properties
    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public ICollection<InvestmentClubMember> ClubMembers;
    public ICollection<InvestmentClubPolicy> Policies;
}
```

**InvestmentClubPolicy class**

```
public class InvestmentClubPolicy
{
    public int InvestmentClubPolicyId { get; set; }
    public int InvestmentClubId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public string PolicyStatement { get; set; }
    public AjoPolicyStatus PolicyStatus { get; set; }
    public InvestmentClub InvestmentClub { get; set; }
}
```

I did not specify the properties as virtual as I didn't want eager loading of the related objects. Could this be the reason for the error? All help is eagerly anticipated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClubMembers` is declared as a field, but EntityFramework requires it to be a property. Declare it as following:

```
public ICollection<InvestmentClubMember> ClubMembers { get; set; };
```

Comment: You are right Alexander. I just observed it now. I guess its time to take a break.

Answer (score 3):

```
public ICollection<InvestmentClubMember> ClubMembers;
```

should be

```
public virtual ICollection<InvestmentClubMember> ClubMembers { get; set; }
```

...or better yet,

```
public virtual ICollection<InvestmentClubMember> ClubMembers { get; protected set; }
```

It needs to be `virtual` in order for the dynamic proxy subclass to be able to populate the navigation property. They will not eager load automatically just because the property is `virtual`.

The `.Include` extension method is what does the eager loading.

Comment: Its working now without the virtual. The problem was that I mistakenly declared ClubMembers as a field instead of a property.